# What is my Wireless Router IP Address When it's as a Bridge

Tags: networking, ip-address, gateway, control-panel, bridge-router

I have a (TP-Link WR940N) Wireless Router in my Home.

**My PC IP add is 192.168.10.222** and in my PC **Default Gateway is 192.168.10.1**

When I want to open my TP-Link Admin Panel by Default gateway (192.168.10.1) that's opening my ISP (Mikrotik) Router Login Page.

Now - how can I find my own TP-Link IP Address?

Comment: You need to set the tp-link to another 192.168.10.x IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bridge is not a gateway. It will likely have an IP address from DHCP, like other regular devices, so check the Mikrotik router's DHCP lease table first.

The TP-Link *might* have a static address configured instead (even one in a completely wrong subnet – this doesn't actually affect its function as a bridge). If you don't see it in the Mikrotik "DHCP server" lease list, try an IP scanner app (Mikrotik routers have such a function built in).

(Another way to detect an unknown IP address of a device is to fire up Wireshark on some machine on the bridge's Ethernet side, or even on the Mikrotik, then restart the TP-Link and look for any packets coming from its MAC address – e.g. filtering by `eth.src == ab:cd:...` – until you see an ARP packet or something that hints at the TP-Link's IP address.)

Comment: Also the Out-coming Internet Cable is not connected to my TP-Link's WAN Port, That's Connected to LAN of my Router.